# "Well-defined" ordering on the set of equivalence classes

Tags: logic

I'm trying to work my way through Herbert Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*, and I'm currently stuck on the following exercise (3.2.3, to be precise):

> Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a model of $\text{Th }\mathfrak{N}_L$. For $a$ and $b$ in $\vert\mathfrak{A}\vert$ define the equivalence relation: \begin{align*}a\sim b\Longleftrightarrow\ &\mathbf{S}^\mathfrak{A}\text{ can be applied a finite number of times to one of}\\&a,b\text{ to reach the other.}\end{align*}Let $[a]$ be the equivalence class to which $a$ belongs. Order equivalence classes by $$[a]\prec[b]\text{ iff }a<^\mathfrak{A}b\text{ and }a\nsim b.$$Show that this is a well-defined ordering on the set of equivalence classes.

where $\mathfrak{N}_L=\left(\mathbb{N};0,S,<\right)$ and $S$ is the successor function.

I'm really not sure how to go about solving this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated. In particular, I'm not sure what the difference between an *ordering* and a *well-defined ordering* is. I do know, though, that for a relation to be an ordering, it needs to be transitive and satisfy trichotomy on the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well-defined ordering* is **not** a particular type of order; it means that the *order* so defined is [well-defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined), i.e. it does not depend on the single representative of the equivalence class.

In full :

having defined the equivalence classes by :

> > $[a] ≺ [b]$ iff $a <^A b$ and $a≁b$,

if we consider : $a_1 ∼ a$ and $b_1 ∼ b$, it still holds that :

> $[a_1] ≺ [b_1]$.

---

For *transitivity*, we have to show that :

> if $[a] ≺ [b]$ and $[b] ≺ [c]$, then $[a] ≺ [c]$.

The "obvious part" : if $a < b$ and $b < c$, then $a < c$, follows from Axiom (L5) [see page 194].

We have to prove also that : if $a ≁ b$ and $b ≁ c$, then $a ≁ c$.

Assume not, i.e. $a ∼ c$; this means that, for some $n$ : $c=S^na$ (because : $a < c$).

But this implies $c \in [a]$ and thus, by "well-definition" of the equivalence relation, that $[c]=[a]$.

So, by $[c]=[a]$ and $[a] ≺ [b]$ we have that : $[c] ≺ [b]$ and this implies $c < b$, contradicting the fact that $b < c$.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But how do I show that $\prec$ is transitive and satisfies trichotomy?